# Are other supernaturals resistant to reality changes brought by demons and angels?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

As we know The god machine can create new covers for its angels (like a brother appearing out of thin air, ...). Demons on the other hand can become someones spouse, brother, .... .

Now I'm wondering if other supernatural beings have at least some sort of defense or resistance against this, such that they can notice something's changed, or that things aren't the way they always were?

As example: Take the vampire prince of the city who is in reality a demon (since a few weeks) and switches gender through a pact. Does any normally affected vampire there have some resistance? Do they have any chance of recognising the vampire prince has changed?

Comment: Resistance i.e. the ability to perceive that something is new or changed, that this person didn't always have a brother, this person wasn't always a woman?

Comment: exactly like that

Answer (score 4):

**No** and **yes** and **everyone would notice anyway**, respectively.

The description of a God-Machine-created Cover granted to an angel only refers to altering *human* memories retroactively.

> A demon’s Cover is more than just a human body to live
>   in and a name to call it by. The God-Machine’s Infrastructure
>   actually alters reality around its servants, creating an entire,
>   albeit austere, life for the angel in question. It can’t (or doesn’t)
>   create human beings out of whole cloth, but it *can* alter human
>   memories to include the new arrival and it can create objects
>   and even places to support an angel’s existence.

A demon begins with a Cover like this from its creator, and can steal a new one with angel-jacking, but after the Fall they're limited to using pacts to construct new Covers, which are much more limited both in only  shuffling around pre-existing bits of reality and in the scope of whose memories they can alter, but don't require the altered minds to be human:

> When a demon makes a pact (see p. 116), she may stipulate
>   some aspect of the other party’s life as the consideration.
>   When this pact is called in, her Cover absorbs that piece of
>   reality, effectively “editing out” the human and “editing in” the
>   demon. The demon and the human both remember reality as it
>   “really” is, but other directly-affected parties simply remember
>   the demon as having always been involved in their lives with no
>   recollection of the person she replaced.

And patching in a new *gender* via a pact has no 'directly-affected parties' beyond yourself, so changing genders would fail to alter anyone's memories at all, human or otherwise, and seems like it would be an enormous liability for compromise. (There's also the distracting question of *what happened to the pactbound who sold away their gender*? What would they look like afterwards with 'no' gender at all left in its place?)

Not to mention that a Demon's Cover is always human, and would lack all the distinctive supernatural traits of a vampire without the constant use of Deep Cover and Show of Power. Per "Pacts and Other Creatures of the Night", even if a demon claimed a vampire's soul with a pact a few weeks ago:

> the demon only assumes the being’s identity...but
>   as a human being. If she claims a vampire’s soul, she takes that
>   vampire’s name and face, but is not undead, does not drink blood,
>   and does not necessarily know the intricacies of vampire society.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

In general, a good passage is page 194 of DtD:  "Pacts and Other Creatures of the Night"

This passage implies that other supernatural types are treated as normal mortals in regards to pacts. Ergo, it makes sense to say that, since mortals have no "inherent advantage" to detecting pact-based changes, and supernaturals are treated largely the same in regards to pacts, it is logical that supernaturals would have no inherent advantage.

From another angle, page 122 details the Clash of Wills, emphasis mine:

> Sometimes, two supernatural *powers* oppose one another.

From the description of pacts, page 189, emphasis mine:

> All demons can forge pacts, and this *ability* does keep more than a few demon philosophers awake at night.

Two pages later:

> When a contract is destroyed, the pact is immediately nullified.

So, in this sense, Demon have the ability to anchor changes in reality in the form of Pacts; this is a differentiation from their powers to passively or actively alter reality (with Embeds and Exploits, respectively.)

Now, it could be argued that Mages (because of their resonance with different realities) might have some advantage to track down changes to reality (through Fate spells or somesuch) but I am not familiar enough with them to know of something offhand.

For the specific example of a Demon masquerading as the Vampire Prince and doing a gender swap, that would be a very disadvantageous situation. First, in order to gain praxis, the demon would have to convince a Prince to either sign away his soul or his praxis; and, in the case of a soul pact, the passage on 194 details that the Demon would take aggravated damage, and the resultant cover would be a normal mortal, unable to pass for a Vampire.

Now, assuming the Demon had Deep Cover from Flowers of Hell, they could spoof as a Vampire - bearing in mind it'd be a roll for every scene, with a dicepool of 10 or less. Add to that, that Deep Cover just provides protection from detection attempts. Assuming the Demon has Show of Power, that's an Exploit - every time the fake Prince needs to demonstrate his Celerity or Majesty, you're running risk of Compromise - and that's not even taking into account that Show of Power is contested.

But, the circumstances that drove a Demon into such a precarious situation certainly sound intriguing, to say the least.